# I thought I understood voltage drop in DC circuits until this

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, voltage

I drew a sketch.[image: Diagram of circuit] I hope it helps.  Assume pigtail is disconnected from socket, as are the wires to the lamps.  My voltage drop is occurring "upriver" of where I expect it.  I figured on $12\,\mathrm{V}$ all the way to the lamps, then $0\,\mathrm{V}$ after, with both brown and black having to keep the same reading.  Looks like I don't understand this.

Comment: Could you specify your question more explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Very few power sources are "ideal voltage sources."  Most degrade when you put a load on them.  This is typically modeled by an "internal resistance" of the voltage source that is in series with the source and the load.

When you start to draw a lot of current through a real voltage source, you'll find the voltage goes down due to this effect.  How much it goes down depends on your source.  A small AA may go down quickly as you pull more current.  A 120V wall socket may support quite a lot more current before issues appear (those issues will show up as a "brown out" where the power to the circuit seems to falter)